# Overflow-x scroll not working in tr

Tags: html, css

I have a Table that contain a tr in this tr there is several td i need to have overflow-x scroll but it isn't working.

```
  <tr id="TR_TESTS_BY_CAT" width="100%" height="480px" style="display: none;         overflow-x:scroll">
    <td height="530px" valign="top" id="TD_TESTS1" style="width: 25%">
                                <div id="divTests1" style="height: 530px; width: 100%;  vertical-align: top;">
                                </div>
                            </td>
 <td>.....</td>
```

.....

but it isn't working

Comment: a note : overflow-x:scroll is css3, so are you testing in  a compatible browser?

Comment: also place the css in the div

Comment: is there a way to do it in IE 8

Comment: yes sally check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give your td specific sizes: `width:200px;` this will set the size and the div should also get a width equal or lower, so the there wont be a horizontal scroll.

This is a work around obviously. if you want to get the best solution you can switch to using `<div>` instead of tables and and avoiding inline css. You can only imagine how much more you can do with css styling.

Comment: It would be better to switch my td to <div> :)

Answer (score 4):

`overflow` is not applicable to `<TR>`s by definition. TR (display:table-row) is not a block element - does not establish box (remember col/rowspans in cells).

Only block-alike elements (display:block | inline-block | list-item) have concept of overflow as they have box were to scroll.

Comment: +1 for "Only block-alike elements (display:block | inline-block | list-item) have concept of overflow"